# Woocommerce display taxonomy title in current taxonomy archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy

So, I have in the menu a link to a taxonomy archive that shows every product associated with that taxonomy.
Wordpress shows the correct page-title in category/tag archive, instead it shows the latest product title in the taxonomy page, that is nonsense.

I know that there's something about **archive.php**

```
elseif ( is_category() )

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'mirage' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );

elseif ( is_tag() )

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Tag Archives: %s', 'mirage' ), '<span>' . single_tag_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );

elseif ( is_day() )

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'mirage' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' );
```

I tried to add an **is_tax()** etc. but nothing seems to reflect on the frontend.

I need to get the current taxonomy name and put it in the same page title.

Hope I made it clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
elseif ( is_product_taxonomy() )
    single_term_title();
endif;
```